# VBA Application.Workbooks.Open(file_name.xls) opens already opened workbook instead of file_name passed

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to open a workbook using Application.Workbooks.Open by passing the file name along with path as an argument. 
If any other excel is opened it is activating opened excel instead of opening excel with the given file name

My Code :

```
Dim rsWB As Workbook
Dim fname As String

fname = "C:\Users\test\my development\ouput\new_output.xlsx"
Set rsWB = Application.Workbooks.Open(fname)

rsWB.Activate
MsgBox (rsWB.Name)
```

Case 1. If no other excel file is open. rsWB.Name = new_output.xlsx

Case 2. If output.xlsx is already open. rsWB.Name = output.xlsx

Comment: Is this literally your code, or is this extracted from a larger set?  I've never seen the workbook returned from Open() be anything other than the filename passed in.

Comment: Yes. It was part of the existing code block, but I had pasted the exact lines causing the problem. I am not sure what is causing it.

Comment: This is a known bug. You must first test whether or not your workbook is already open in Excel.